# Windows xp: roll my own desktop tool to copy list of directory names

Tags: windows, copy, mkdir, directory-listing

Many times I have found the need to copy directory names from one directory into another, creating a list of empty directories in the later.

I have achieved this task using the following command:

```
for /F "usebackq" %i IN (`dir /b C:/backups/sites/24/01/2012`) DO makdir C:\fabio_temp\test\%i
```

Now i would like to create a reusable and friendly tool so that i don't have to be typing this all the time on the command line.

Example of what I want in pseudo-language:

```
$dir = PROMPT('Type in the name of the directory containing the list of directories to clone:');
$dir_dest = PROMPT('Type in the destination directory:');

FOREACH LIST_DIRNAMES($dir) AS $dirname DO
    MKDIR CONCAT($dir_dest,$dirname)
ENDFOREACH;
```

Then, it would be nice to have this function appearing in the right-click context menu. It doesn't matter what language is going to be used for this. It could be vbscript, or whatever, I don't know.

Comment: Do you have an actual programming question? This just looks like it belongs on your blog.

Comment: @Oded I think fabio wants only a script to do the task he wrote about. I can suggest to fabio to check out for Windows commands and how to do batch scripts. --> http://commandwindows.com/batch.htm

Comment: @AlbertoSolano - Then its off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tutorial that @AlbertoSolano suggested, I was able to write a simple script named `mkdirs_from_list.bat` with the following content:

```
for /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`dir %1 /b`) DO mkdir %2\%%i
```

That does exactly what I was asking for, and, to make things easier, I'm adding the script to the path environment, so it can be invoked like this on the command line:

```
mkdirs_from_list C:\dir_to_list C:\dir_dest
```

I wanted something more friendly, like a prompt popping up, being able to browse the directories, or something alike, but I think this will suffice.

Comment: I'm glad the link suggested helped you. :-)